# How to store a trained Random Forest model in python or matlab as a matrix

Tags: python, random-forest, matlab

Is it possible to store a random forest model in python (or matlab). Then use that trained model in a C program?

I am trying to do this because I am making a myoelectric prosthetic, and you can only write to the chip we are using (PIC32MK0512MCF064) with C code.

My first thought on how to attempt this was to store the model as a matrix but I dont know if that is even possible?

Any clues? anything that could help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about a matrix, but here's a repo for porting sklearn models into other languages, including C.

https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much